# Reference Request: Embeddable operators

Tags: reference-request, semigroup-of-operators

In [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.554.9214&rep=rep1&type=pdf) article, the author studies linear operators on Banach Spaces which can be embedded into a $C_0-$semigroup.

> A linear operator $T$ on a Banach space $X$ is said to be embeddable if there exists a $C_0-$semigroup $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ such that $T=T(1).$

I would like some recommendations on books/articles which talks about embeddable operators and talks about the importance of such operators.

Comment: I believe that it was in the literature of this professor. That is, look at her homepage, the books that the professor wrote. I am saying that I believe that the book that you need should be Tanja Eisner, *Stability of Operators and Operator Semigroups*, Operator Theory: Advances and Applications, Vol. 209. Birkhäuser Verlag, Basel, 2010. Notice that the web of Springer provide you the link **Download Preface 1 PDF**. Good luck.

Comment: I hope that other users can provide you references for talks or articles.